# Making a namepaced function asynchronous using setimeout

Tags: javascript

I have this function which is using namespace. I want to make it asynchronous. Assuming that this function is being called on click of some button ?

```
var ns = {
            somemfunc: function (data) {
                alert("hello");
            }
        }
```

EDIT - Sorry for being unclear on this. I want to make the call to this function asynchronous by putting the settimeout function inside the somefunc function. Not sure how to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can either set the timeout when you call the function, or put the timeout within the somefunc function.

Comment: This question should probably be called `Making a synchronous function asynchronous` because it doesn't have anything to do with it being within the scope of `ns`

Comment: I did not got it , could you please clarify?

Comment: What does "asynchronous" mean to you? You cannot just "make it" asynchronous. What is the problem you are trying to solve? Doesn't the function do what you want?

Comment: Right now this function is being called synchronously. I want the call to be asynchronous and then a time out 60 secs.

Comment: Forget the term "asynchronous" for now and explain the behavior you are looking for..end to end. In other words what problem are you trying to solve

Comment: "Asynchronous" usually is used to refer to a function which takes some time to do its work, and then somehow reports back that it is done, via a callback or by returning a promise. You're not doing any of that. You're just trying to execute something 60 seconds from now. The correct way to describe that is "I want something to execute after a timeout. You can do that real easy using `setTimeout`, which is well documented in all the usual places. Also, this is not a "namespaced function". It's just a method on an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set this function to be called asynchronously by adding a `setTimeout` block within the definition of `somefunc`, note that I am using the term asynchronous loosely here as this function isn't really doing any asynchronous work.  An async function would be a function that does some work that takes some time to execute, such as making a network request, aggregating its results and then reporting back to the caller to do some sort of DOM refresh or something, it normally reports back to the caller using a callback, or resolving/rejecting a promise, in the time that this long running code is running, the Event Queue is not blocked and can continue to process other actions if this was not the case then the app would be unresponsive until the long running task finished computing.

What you want to achieve here is not truly async as you're simply scheduling the function to run on the Event Queue in 2 seconds.

```
var ns = {
    somemfunc: function (data) {
       setTimeout(function() {
            alert("hello");
       }, 2000);
    }
}

ns.somemfunc();
```

When `ns.somefunc()` is called, its now set to execute the function `somefunc` on the Event Queue in 2000ms (2 seconds).  Remember Javascript is single threaded, tasks are scheduled to run on the event queue and will be processed contiguously.  If you set the timeout to run the function after 2000ms but the jobs before it take 500ms to compute, then we actually wait 2500ms for the queue to serve that function.

Comment: Calls are not asynchronous; functions are.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the learning that has been provided. I am new to JS. So still scratching the surface.